# php convert excel data into 3d array

Tags: php, excel, multidimensional-array

I have an excel file whose data is a 3d array.

[image]

I am using PHPExcel Object to return the data into 3d array. But I can only return a 2d array.

```
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
    $cell_collection = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellCollection();
    foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {
        $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getCell($cell)
        ->getColumn();
        $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getCell($cell)
        ->getRow();
        $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getCell($cell)
        ->getValue();
        if ($row == 1) {
            $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        } else {
            $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        }
  }
```

How can I return a result array like this:

```
$res = array(
    [2]=>array(
        [A] => A,//column A
        [B] =>array([1]=>'red',[2]=>'pink',[3]=>'purple')
     ),
    [3]=>array(
        [A] => B,//column B
        [B] =>array([1]=>'white',[2]=>'blue',[3]=>'black')
     ),
);
```

Anyone knows how I could modify my code to return the expected result? Any answer would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a php programmer and this code not complied. Here I have added my code to generate your expected array. It can help you to solve your problem. I think $column is a column value like A,B.....

```
 $i = 1;
 $i_str = "";
 $res = array();
 foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) {

        $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
        $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
        $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();

        if ($row == 1) {
            $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
        } else {

            if($column == 'A' && $data_value != ""){
                $i++;
                $i_str = (string) $i;
                $res[$i_str]['A'] = $data_value;
                $res[$i_str]['B'] = array();

            }
            else if($column == 'B'){
                $len = (string) (count($res[$i_str]['B']) + 1);
                $res[$i_str]['B'][$len] = $data_value;

            }

        }
  }

  print_r($res) // here you will get your expected array
```